# PHP to import a csv file to an existing mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a file called `aaa.csv` that is already located in the server. I am trying to load it into an existing, but empty `MySQL` Table. The number of columns of the existing table is the same as in the `csv` file. The structure of the `csv` file is like this:

```
Name/Note/Average
"PEREZ, JUAN"/7/7.4
"BENITO, ALVARO"/8.3/5
```

So, the `php` code I am using is as follows:

```
MYSQL_CONNECT('db56569XXXXX.db.1and1.com','dbo56569xxxx','mypassword') 
    or die("Servidor sin conexión");

MYSQL_SELECT_DB('db565699064') or die('La base de datos no existe');

$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE 'aaa.csv' INTO TABLE TABLE11 "
    . "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES";

$res=mysql_query($sql);
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I don't get any error message, but `TABLE11` is still empty.

Comment: try passing the full path not just 'aaa.csv' - ie "/var/www/uploads/aaa.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Try with an absolute URL for your file like this :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/csv.csv' INTO TABLE TABLE11 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES
```